# 2D Box Problem Energy Spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am trying to connect some of the ideas I have learned "pre-dirac" notation to dirac notation. In the past I have solved the problem of the 2D well (of length $(L,L)$). The normalized energy states are:

$$\psi_{n_x, n_y} = \frac{2}{L} \sin(\frac{n_x \pi x}{L}) \sin(\frac{n_y \pi y}{L})$$
$$ E_{n_x, n_y} = \frac{(n_x^2 + n_y^2) \pi^2 \hbar^2}{2mL^2}$$

If I understand this correctly this is my energy spectrum. Hence for $ |\phi \rangle$ the state can be expanded to:

$$ |\phi \rangle = \sum_{n_x} \sum_{n_y} c_{n_x, n_y}| \psi_{n_x, n_y} \rangle$$

To find the values of $c_{n_x, n_y}$ I would need to compute $ c_{n_x, n_y} = \langle \phi| \psi_{n_x, n_y} \rangle$. Hence, am I right in assuming would need to know that the initial state I am starting with $ |\phi \rangle$ in order to do this decomposition?

I am trying to match an actual experimental concept to this idea. Let's say I generate a particle in a $(0, L/2)_2$ box in its ground state. Then, seting it in its first initial state:

$$ |\phi \rangle = \frac{1}{L} \sin(\frac{n_x \pi x}{2L}) \sin(\frac{n_y \pi y}{2L})$$

Then let's say I expand the potential to the $(L,L)$ case, and I want to know the probability of it appearing in the first energy level of the new potential. Then would this be the correct condition?

$$ c=\langle \psi_{1,1}|\phi \rangle = \int_{\Omega}dxdy \frac{2}{L} \sin(\frac{\pi x}{L}) \sin(\frac{\pi y}{L}) \frac{1}{L} \sin(\frac{\pi x}{2L}) \sin(\frac{\pi y}{2L})$$

Lastly, this 2D model is often used to exemplify how electrons in an atom can be promoted to higher energy states. If I have an electron in its ground state, then $ |\phi \rangle = | \psi_{1,1} \rangle$. How exactly can this be "promoted" to a higher energy state if any other higher energy state $\langle \psi_{n_x, n_y}| \psi_{1,1} \rangle = 0$?